# Finding location of executable in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

My actual goal is to read from a file in the parent directory of the executable. I first tried to solve this by doing the following. That works mostly fine, but when running in Rider on my macbook the exeDir resolves to `/usr/local/share`

```
var exeDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule?.FileName);
var parentDir = Directory.GetParent(exeDir).FullName;
```

The reason for this is that Rider executes the application by doing this

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
>   /Users/thomas/RiderProjects/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/ConsoleApp1.dll

Leading to `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule?.FileName` resulting in `/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet`.

---

After doing some research I tried using one of these instead

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

Instead of reporting `C:\dummyservice` as expected when running on a windows host, I get this result:

> C:\Users\THOMAS~1\AppData\Local\Temp.net\worker\otstv4uv.ifx\worker.dll

This is because of how dotnet unpacks bundled applications, ie. `PublishSingleFile=true`. Thanks to @OmairMajid in the comments pointing this out.

I am still looking for suggestions for how to handle this in a platform independent way.

---

Summarized, this is what I want to achieve. The dotnet core 3.0 worker application is bundled with a different application.

```
C:\MyApp
C:\MyApp\config.ini
C:\MyApp\... # other files (executables, …)
C:\MyApp\Worker\Worker.exe # installed as service, want to read config.ini above
```

Comment: Yes, `PublishSingleFile=true` definitely affects it. The single file version is extracted to disk and then that extracted executible is executed. See [the `PublishSingleFile` design doc](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/single-file/extract.md#extraction-location).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! @OmairMajid

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, in Win is working also in .net core

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

[Update] With PublishSingleFIle=true there is the same issue on Win, the given directory will be C:\Temp.net\ConsoleApp\uxohf4qt.col\

There is an interesting discussion on .net core github
https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/52

Comment: This also results in ` C:\Users\THOMAS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\.net\worker\otstv4uv.ifx` when published with PublishSingleFile=true